# Protect email and password using ActionMailler in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer, password-protection, environments

I've gotten the action mailer to work, but I want to make sure I'm protecting the username/password combination that I end up using.  This is being developed for ea company and will be using their credentials, email address, etc

Here's what I have using my Gmail as a test in the development environment:

```
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: "127.0.0.1",
    authentication: "login",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: "emailaddress@gmail.com",
    password: "mypassword"
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right to want to protect the password.

If you're using an older version of Rails (4.0 or less) you can use the Figaro gem found here...

https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro

You will have a 'config/application.yml' file which (by default) will NOT be uploaded to your repository.  You would include in it...

```
email_user_name: "emailaddress@gmail.com"
email_password: "mypassword"
```

And then in your environment(s) you use...

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: "127.0.0.1",
    authentication: "login",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: ENV["email_user_name"],
    password: ENV["email_password"]
  }
```

... and it all works wonderfully.  On production you set your environment variables to the secreted information.

Rails 4.1 provides a `secrets.yml` that works similarly...

```
development:
  email_user_name: emailaddres@gmail.com
  email_password: mypassword
```

...and then in use, you retrieve the values with...

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: "127.0.0.1",
    authentication: "login",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: Rails.application.secrets.email_user_name,
    password: Rails.application.secrets.email_password
  }
```

Comment: I created a .local_env.yml file and stored those email settings in there as env variables, but when the people I'm working with pull this existing version from github they have to remake that local_env.yml file otherwise the server can't launch.  I'm guessing the secrets.yml is a better option...and I'm guessing this is also automaticcally in your ignore file?

Comment: Well, no... secrets.yml is not automatically in your gitignore, surprisingly. The way it's populated when you do `rails new Myapp` you'll see it expect confidential info to be in ENV. There is a gem that makes it behave more like the Figaro solution, the name of the gem escapes me at the moment but I'll post another comment when I get back to my desk... or you might find it by googling.